# Как делить на предикативные единицы предложение с однородными членами? Они будут входить в одну предикативную единицу?

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые, сложное-предложение, подлежащее

Сила, свобода, любовь - всё это было отнято у нас и отдано другим.

Сколько здесь предикативных единиц?

Как они выглядят?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Сила, свобода, любовь - всё это было отнято у нас и отдано другим*.

Это простое предложение, осложнённое однородными членами и обобщающим словом. Это одна предикативная единица. Предикативная основа - сила, свобода, любовь - всё это было отнято  и отдано.